# how to add a related field many2one?

Tags: field, odoo

I have a field on stock_picking table I would like to relate it with stock_move

```
 _inherit= 'stock.picking' 
 _columns={
        'user_id': fields.many2one('res.users', 'user', select=True),
}
```

I would like to relate the field user_id with stock_move 
I tried this

```
 _inherit= 'stock.move' 
 _columns={
  'user_id': fields.related('picking_id', 'user_id', relation="res.users", type='many2one', string="user", store=True, readonly=True)
}
```

any Idea brothers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used wrong model in `inherit` it should be as follows:

```
 _inherit= 'stock.picking' 
 _columns={
        'user_id': fields.many2one('res.users', 'user', select=True),
}

 _inherit= 'stock.move' 
 _columns={
  'user_id': fields.related('picking_id', 'user_id', relation="res.users", type='many2one', string="user", store=True, readonly=True)
}
```

Comment: I edited the ans.. you have wrongly written the keyword `_columns` as `_column`.

Comment: it's not depending on _column in my code I have _columns

Comment: the column user_id couldn't be updated, I droped it from the table & I tried it work fine now

Answer (score 3):

Agree with @Hardik Patadia. But you may also try with `type=char`

```
_inherit= 'stock.picking' 
_columns={
    'user_id': fields.many2one('res.users', 'user', select=True),
}

_inherit= 'stock.picking.in' 
_columns={
    'user_id': fields.many2one('res.users', 'user', select=True),
}

_inherit= 'stock.picking.out' 
_columns={
    'user_id': fields.many2one('res.users', 'user', select=True),
}

_inherit= 'stock.move' 
_columns={
    'user_id': fields.related('picking_id', 'user_id', 'name', type='char', string='User', store=True, readonly=True ), 
}
```

Comment: the column user_id on the table stock_move stil empty !!

Comment: the column user_id couldn't be updated, I droped it from the table & I tried it work fine now